# Webpage not adjusting to webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

[Not important]
We have 2 web pages that display our network infrastructure on a dual monitor computer and there fixed at a size of 1920 x 1080. The problem is that we have to manually move the browsers the pages are displayed in to put them on the correct screen every morning after our displays have been turned off in the evening.
[/not important]

To avoid this hassle I thought about making a vb.net application with 2 forms and a browser control on each of them and let the forms open on 2 different screens when the program is run(after a reboot). This works, however, the pages are not displayed correctly in the browser control. It's like they are zoomed in, while they appear normal in Firefox which has been maximized(f11).

I hope someone can point me in the right direction of how to fix this.

As you can see, I tried a couple of things my self but it still will not work.

```
Public Class Left

Private Sub Left_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Me.Location = New Point(Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.X, Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.Y)
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    Me.TopMost = True

    'WebBrowser1.Visible = True

    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://detectmybrowser.com/") 'Just an example


    'WebBrowser1.AllowNavigation = False

    'WebBrowser1.Document.Body.Style = String.Format("zoom: {0}%", 50)
    TopRight.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    TopRight.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks for any help you guys can give me. 
:)

Comment: I'm confused, what is the exact issue here?

Comment: "the pages are not displayed correctly in the browser control."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved. I used an other browser control, awesomium, which supported a zoom option.
Then I added the new control to the form and put in this:

```
Public Class Left

Private Sub Left_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.Location = New Point(Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.X, Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.Y)
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    Me.TopMost = True

End Sub

Private Sub Awesomium_Windows_Forms_WebControl_LoadingFrameComplete(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Awesomium.Core.FrameEventArgs) Handles WebControl2.LoadingFrameComplete
    WebControl2.Zoom = "80"
    TopRight.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```